# Routing problems with outlets, lazyloading and multiple child layers

Tags: angular

I am trying to have multiple layers of lazy loaded routes
All navigating to a named outlet.
Having only 2 layers (main and child) works
But navigating to a child from a child fails.
With the error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'name of first child'

So directing to a component in the first child level works.
but going from this child to a child of this child will give me the error.

**app.routing:**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'desktop-layout', component: DesktopLayoutComponent, children: [
    { path: 'mainmenu-page', component: MainMenuPageComponent, outlet: 'multiUseMenu' },
    { path: 'logviewer-app', loadChildren: './Logging/logviewer-app/logviewer-app.module#LogviewerAppModule', outlet: 'multiUseMenu' },
    { path: 'batch-log-app', loadChildren: './batch-selector/batch-selector.module#BatchSelectorModule', outlet: 'multiUseMenu' }, 
      { path: 'job-editor-app', loadChildren: './job-editor-app/job-editor-app.module#JobEditorAppModule', outlet: 'multiUseMenu' },
      { path: 'capture-service-log', loadChildren: './Logging/capture-service-log/capture-service-log.module#CaptureServiceLogModule', outlet: 'multiUseMenu' },
    { path: 'input-profile-editor-app', loadChildren: './inputsettings-profile-app/inputsettings-profile-app.module#InputsettingsProfileAppModule', outlet: 'multiUseMenu' },  
  ]},
{ path: 'login-page', component: LoginPageComponent },
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { enableTracing: true,useHash:true }), LoginManagerModule],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**BatchSelectorAppRouting:**

```
const batchselector_routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    redirectTo: 'batchselector'
  },  
  {
    path: 'batchselector', component: BatchselectorComponent, children: [
      { path: 'idrlogviewer', loadChildren: '../Logging/logviewer-app/logviewer-app.module#LogviewerAppModule', outlet: 'multiUseMenu' },
    ]
  },
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(batchselector_routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class BatchSelectorAppRouting { }
```

**LogviewerAppRouting:**

```
const logviewer_routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: LogviewerAppDblogviewerComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(logviewer_routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class LogviewerAppRouting { }
```

**navigate:**

```
 this.router.navigate(['desktop-layout', { outlets: { multiUseMenu: 'batch-log-app/idrlogviewer' } }]);
```

I think I tried all combinations in the `navigate(['desktop-layout', { outlets: { multiUseMenu: 'idrlogviewer' } }])` etc..
But none of them works.

Hopefully, someone has more experience with this and can help me.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: It so many routes maybe if you removed some just for test and leave just one parent-child-child it’s easier to see any mistakes. I’be done my routing without the ‘outlet’ property

Answer (score 0):

There is an angular feature called ActivatedRoute and it gives you access to the parents and childs route. Use like this :

```
// In the component you are having trouble :

constructor(private readonly activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}

// Then, debug or log(activatedRoute)
```

I don't have a specific solution but try see what's inside this and give the outlet a url to a child's child relative to the **common** parent ?

Comment: I tried this but i am not sure how to read this. When logging the activate rout before the navigate of the child i get the log. The activated route:"/desktop-layout/(multiUseMenu:batch-log-app/batchselector)" does not have children(children: Array(0)). But looking into the routeconfig i see a child with loadChildren: "../Logging/logviewer-app/logviewer-app.module#LogviewerAppModule". So it is in the config but not loaded yet?